# Import Multiple Sheets into Multiple Data Frames in R

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I have an Excel file with a lot of sheets and I need a code to import each sheet in a separate data frame which will be named in the same convention as the sheet name in Excel.

Example, tabs A, B, C will be imported as data frame A, B, and C respectively.

From other threads, I saw codes like:
`length(excel_sheets(filename))`  to get the number of sheets in the file

Then create a list that would contain each tab:

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <-    lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  names(x) <- sheets
  x
}
```

But I do not know how the tabs gets imported into R from there.

Would greatly appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
# write test data
tf <- writexl::write_xlsx(
  list("the mtcars" = mtcars, "iris data" = iris), 
  tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
)

# read excel sheets
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(tf)
lst <- lapply(sheets, function(sheet) 
  readxl::read_excel(tf, sheet = sheet)
)
names(lst) <- sheets

# shove them into global environment
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function reads in all the tabs and saves them as elements of a single list (because of `lapply()`). You can take the elements out of the list with `list2env`:

```
your_excel_list <- read_excel_allsheets("test.xlsx")
list2env(your_excel_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

You'll see that the named elements of your list are now data frames (or actually `tbl_df`) in your global environment

Answer (score 1):

could read in one line.
should load magrittr and dplyr packages.

```
data <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx"),function(x) x=read_excel(x,sheet = "(sheetname)")) %>%  bind_rows
```